# Given a set of numbers, what mathematical name is given to the most frequent number

Tags: statistics, terminology, mathematica

Assume a set of numbers {0,1,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,6,7,8,9}

What mathematical name is given to the number that most frequently occurs?

For example, if I was to count the number of occurrences for each number in the above set, I would note every number occurring once except 4 which occurs 5 times.

Thanks

Comment: A ${\it set}$ contains each of its members exactly once. What you have given is a ${\it multiset}$ where each occurring member has a certain multiplicity, but order is not relevant, or an ${\it array}$ when order is relevant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is called the [mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_%28statistics%29) of the set.

Since you tagged your question "mathematica", I will also mention that the mode is implemented in Mathematica as the [Commonest](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Commonest.html) command.